# Looking for Super User's favourite webcomics!

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

What are your favourite computer related comics? And I don't mean "Webcomic A" or "Webcomic B", but which specific comic episode of Webcomic A? I'm trying to wrap up a blog post that would involve these! Send them in please! :D

Also, mention where you got it from! Max. of 2 entries per user.

**Update:** Please send in (and/or vote for existing) before June 22nd!

Comment: I know you've ruled out A and B, but what about Webcomic Θ? It's obviously the best. ;P

Comment: @DMA57361 Well! Just for the fun of it, you're free that mention that one! :D

Answer (score 22):

Classic xkcd: http://xkcd.com/149/

[image: Sandwich]

Comment: It's so great I just had to get this one as a signed print :-)

Comment: Who would downvote this EPIC comic?

Comment: @slhck *Cough* Women *Cough*

Comment: Or Windows users

Comment: +1 .... I LOVE this one!

Comment: +1, I use this on a daily basis. My roomate knows nothing about computers and he asked what 'sudo' was. I told him that it was one program in linux/unix which would turn the computer into a special 'command mode' which could control other linux/unix computers. I said this was mostly based on good faith and no one really used it ... it was just for emergencies.

Answer (score 21):

I've always had a soft spot for this one:

[Exploits of a Mom](http://www.xkcd.com/327/)

[image: Exploits of a Mom]

Answer (score 19):

[C&H](https://www.explosm.net/comics/2429/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [explosm.net](http://www.explosm.net/db/files/Comics/Rob/nailhead.png))</sub>

Comment: Really like the WTF-ness of this one. :)

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Comment: This makes me glad that for all the problems at my office, we actually have a good, well planned, well thought-out, and even well rehearsed disaster recovery plan. And if a truck hit me on my way to the disaster recovery site, everybody else would probably do what that poor sap is doing in Dilbert's slide.

Answer (score 10):

another XKCD.

[Su Doku](http://www.xkcd.com/74/)

[image: Su Doku]

Answer (score 10):

From http://www.geekherocomic.com/2008/03/04/03042008/

[image]

Comment: I love this one.  It's stack overflow or server fault. Lol

Answer (score 9):

A good one from oatmeal

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I use GNU/Linux and i don't know C++ (or any programming language) and never compiled the kernel. am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Alaukik NO it's just a comic be what you are :)

Comment: They're out of order... you need the Windows one first, then the Mac one, then the Linux one.

Comment: @George I realised :)

Answer (score 9):

Wellington Grey's Miscellanea had some real gems. Sadly, his site does not appear to exist on the internet any longer, but I was able to find one of my favorites.

[image: WIFI KILLS BABIES]

Answer (score 9):

[Linux User at Best Buy](http://xkcd.com/272/)

[image: Linux User at Best Buy]

Answer (score 9):

I had this one hung up on my cubical wall when I was doing phone tech support a few years ago

[Tech Support Cheat Sheet](http://xkcd.com/627/)

[image: Tech Support Cheat Sheet]

EDIT:
Now that I was promoted to the dev team I have this one on my wall

[image: Compiling]

Answer (score 7):

How about [The Oatmeal](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/rapture)?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Gotta love [Basic Instructions](http://basicinstructions.net/):

[image]

Reminds me of the time I gave one of our sales people dual monitors for the first time. I finished up and was about to leave when she asked, "how do I use the other screen, do I need another keyboard and mouse?"

Comment: There’s no personal information at `basicinstructions.net`; is that the C++ expert Scott Meyer?

Answer (score 5):

**Life is too inconvenient** (Oct 27, 1995).

[image]
ps: the next day was, **the important thing is persistence** (Oct 28, 1995)
[image]

and, in a subtle way (Mar 25, 1992),
on, **a command of throughly useless information** `;-)`

[image]

```
Gosh! I could keep quoting the entire works of Bill Watterson!!
```

Comment: So… much… text…

Answer (score 1):

Before there was XKCD there was http://userfriendly.org/. And there still is, and now I feel very, very old. ;)

Comment: If you're old, I'm old. Well woudja look at that? We're the same age. Crap, now I feel old. And even grues get full.